# Prove that for every real number x, there is a real number y such that for every real number z, yz = $(x + z)^2-(x^2+z^2)$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I don't understand how to prove this:

> Prove that for every real number x, there is a real number y such that
>   for every real number z, yz = $(x + z)^2-(x^2+z^2)$

In my understanding, I first have to convert this question into logical operators and I have this: $\exists y\forall z[(x + z)^2-(x^2+z^2)]$

After, I solved for $y$ and I get $y=2x$ but I don't understand what I have to do after it.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you go back and read it again.  There should not be TWO "for every real number z" phrases.  The first says that "for every real number z" there exists such a y such that... while the second says that the same y works "for every real number z".  Those cannot both be true.

Comment: What is $x$? Not stated in your question? Assumed to be real? Also, what axioms are you allowed to assume?

Comment: @user247327 thanks, this was a mistake, I edited. It's indeed x, then y and then z.

Comment: y=x+x works over any commutative ring. You don't even need an identity element.

Comment: So you are given two real numbers $x$ and $z$. The problem then asks you to show that the number $y$ satisfying the given property is also real.

Answer (score 1):

If you want olny to have the solution then y=2x is correct, but if you want to write with a logic formalism so you need to use the logic operator for argument in First-order logic, more specifically the Existential Generalization (EG) and the Universal Generalization (UG). Following

1. $(r+s)^2=r^2+s^2+2rs$
2. $2rs=(r+s)^2-(r^2+s^2)$
3. $(\forall x)(2xs=(x+s)^2-(x^2+s^2))$        (2-UG)
4. $(\forall x)(\exists y=2x)(ys=(x+s)^2-(x^2+s^2))$ (3-EG)
5. $(\forall x)(\exists y=2x)(\forall z)(yz=(x+z)^2-(x^2+z^2))$ (4-UG)